# how to fetch data from mysql which column have data with comma operator?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, rdbms

**Task Table**

```
id      assign_to       task
1       1,2,4           Development
2       2,5,3           Testing
```

**Employee Table**

```
id      Name
1       Dhawan
2       Sachin
3       Dhoni
4       Virat
5       Rohit
```

Here i am trying to get all employee name from employee table and get in assign_to field in task table. so my **output** will be below

```
id      assign_to               task
1       Dhawan, Sachin,Virat    Development
2       Virat, Rohit, Dhoni     Testing
```

Below query i wrote. Can anyone suggest me what will be the query for this

```
select t.*,  from task t inner join employee e on e.id in (t.assign_to)
```

Comment: Don't store your data like that. You should look up normalizing your data. This will lead to nothing but headaches.

Comment: @dfundako so how can we store ? directly by name ?

Comment: Have a task table, an employee table, and then a ManyToMany table that relates task id's to employee id's.

Comment: The best way is to avoid save like comma separated.

Comment: See also my answer to this past question: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your query as:

```
 select t.*,  from task t inner join 
employee e on FIND_IN_SET(e.id, t.assign_to) > 0 
GROUP BY e.id
```

Comment: query not correct

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
select task.id,
(select group_concat(employee.name,',')  
from employee employee  
where  find_in_set(employee.id, task.assign_to)> 0 )  as emp ,   
task.task   
from task task;
```

Comment: logical operator not supporting

Comment: Updated. Please try now.

Comment: this is not working

Comment: Updated again. :(